# rails on rails dynamic select form within cocoon nested subform

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am using cocoon gem to create nested form with dynamic select menus, the thing is I'm no able to pass the form id because is generated dynamically.

**Ex:**

```
id="document_document_lines_attributes_1498139518118_porhseq"
id="document_document_lines_attributes_1498139518118_itemno"
```

**Form:**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_select(:porhseq, PurchaseOrderHeader.all, :id, :ponumber,
      { include_blank: "Select PO" }, {class: "form-control"} ) %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:itemno, PurchaseOrderHeader.order(:ponumber),
      :purchase_order_details, :ponumber, :id, :itemno,
        { include_blank: "Select Item" }, { class: 'form-control' }) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Coffee:**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#document_docuemnt_lines_attributes_itemno').parent().hide()
  itemno = $('#document_docuemnt_lines_attributes_itemno').html()
  console.log(itemno)
  $('#document_docuemnt_lines_attributes_porhseq').change ->
    type = $('#document_docuemnt_lines_attributes_porhseq :selected').text()
    options = $(itemno).filter("optgroup[label=#{type}]").html()
    console.log(options)
    if options
      $('#document_docuemnt_lines_attributes_itemno').html(options)
      $('#document_docuemnt_lines_attributes_itemno').parent().show()
    else
      $('#document_docuemnt_lines_attributes_itemno').empty()
      $('#document_docuemnt_lines_attributes_itemno').parent().hide()
```

Comment: You can define *HTML* `id` and use it as `selector` in the `script`

Comment: Thanks @Pavan, I can do that but it will only work if I add only one nested line. In my case I need to add multiple nested lines.

Comment: And what about defining an `id` at each parent `div` level, and using a child selector? e.g.:`$('#form-group-1 > form')`

Comment: It is not the same question, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128937/how-to-get-input-value-with-cocoon-and-javascript Upon insertion you could then attach the handlers of the select boxes and use just the classes, no need to use the automatically generated ids.